# Prevent Stack Overflow in a Minesweeper Clone

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a Minesweeper clone. Thus far, I've gotten to revealing adjacent tiles when the tile clicked has zero adjacent mines, below is my method for revealing mines.

```cs
struct data
{
    public Button tile;
    public bool mine, flag, clicked;
    public int adjMines;
}

data[,] dat;
//Defaults
Size gridSize = new Size(16, 16);
Size tileSize = new Size(16, 16);
int mines = 40, flags = 0;

bool valid(int x, int y)
{
    return (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && y < gridSize.Height && x < gridSize.Width);
}    


void reveal(Button btn)
{
    btn.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
    start = true;
    btn.Enabled = false;

    //find button clicked, forget everything you ever learned about efficiency.
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize.Width; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < gridSize.Height; j++)
            if (dat[i, j].tile == btn)
            {
                if (dat[i, j].adjMines == 0)
                {
                    for (int ii = -1; ii <= 1; ii++)
                        for (int jj = -1; jj <= 1; jj++)
                            if (valid(i + ii, j + jj))
                                reveal(dat[i + ii, j + jj].tile);
                }
                else
                    btn.Text = dat[i, j].adjMines.ToString();
            }
}
```

I keep getting a `StackOverflowException` when I run it, which doesn't come as much of a surprise, but I don't know how to fix it without doing away with the `struct`, which is a requirement. Any ideas?

Comment: what does the `valid` function do?

Comment: Added it. It's just a `bool` that detects whether a given pair of ordinates is within the bounds of the grid.

Comment: Tip: separate your UI from your model. Make the board just represent the board state, then make an UI that only draws it and responds to user actions. Tip 2: don't use mutable structs.

Comment: why not just doing iterative instead of recursion?

Comment: I recommend creating a `IEnumerable<Point> Neighbours(Point p)` function. That will simplify the rest of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would probably help if you didn't recursively try to reveal the same tile:

```
                for (int ii = -1; ii <= 1; ii++)
                    for (int jj = -1; jj <= 1; jj++)
                        if (valid(i + ii, j + jj) && !(ii == 0 && jj == 0))
                            reveal(dat[i + ii, j + jj].tile);
```

Note the `!(ii == 0 && jj == 0)` test added - that will stop one of the stack overflow reasons. Apart from that, you also need to mark the node as 'enabled' before going recursive, it'll keep bouncing back and forth otherwise.

It's not a really efficient method you've chosen to implement, but it should work with this fix.

Comment: I think he needs some way to _not_ iterate if he's already revealed that one - throw in a check for `dat[i + ii, j + jj].tile.Enabled` (or just return from revealed if `btn.Enabled` is false)

Comment: @VisualMelon correct, there were 2 bugs and I only saw the first hehe. Fixed my post, thanks.

Comment: No, it's not even a little efficient. After your fix, I was still getting the exception, so I nested `if (dat[i + ii, j + jj].tile.Enabled)` above the recursive call to see if the target tile had already been revealed. Works perfectly now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that when you "reveal", you reveal all the neighbors. When the neighbor is revealed, it reveals all of *its* neighbours, including the first one, and now you have an infinite recursion.

The trick is: before you reveal the very first one, make a hash set of "in progress reveals". Before you recurse, add the current button to the "in progress" set. In the reveal method **return immediately if the button is already in the in-progress set**. You know that all its neighbours are already in the process of being revealed, so there's no work to do.

Comment: This is one of the two causes of the stack overflow - the other is the peculiar way of selecting the 8 neighbours which also includes the 9th - the node itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling reveal from inside reveal.  Reveal goes through each tile.  You are calling it for all adjacent tiles which then goes through each tile and then calls all adjacent tiles.  I would suggest looking through your use of recursion.